# String Transformation in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, escaping

How can I transform the string like this, I need to convert two double quotes to a \".

```
"Alexandra ""Alex""",Menendez,alex.menendez@gmail.com,Miami,1
["Alexandra \"Alex\"", "Menendez", "alex.menendez@gmail.com", "Miami", "1"]
```

the return should be a list and that's where I am landing into a problem. This is what I came up with

```
def parseCsv(sentence):
    result = []
    new_result = []
    sent_1 = list(sentence)
    new_str = ""
    new_w = ""

    for s in sent_1:
        if s != ',':
            new_str += " ".join(s)
        elif new_str:
            result.append(new_str)
            new_str = ""
    result.append(new_str)

    for i, w in enumerate(result):
        if w.startswith("\"") or w.endswith("\""):
            new_w += result[i]
            if new_w.startswith("\"") and new_w.endswith("\""):
                x = new_w.replace('""', r'\"')
                new_result.append(x)
                new_w = ""
        else:
            new_result.append(w)
    return new_result
```

What I get back instead is

```
['"Alexandra \\"Alex\\""', 'Menendez', 'alex.menendez@gmail.com', 'Miami', '1']
```

Comment: can you try doing a `for` loop to print out the contents?

Comment: by the way you can use Python's `string.split(',')` to form a list of words separated by commas

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to do anything. The `csv` module will load your data correctly:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

infile = StringIO('"Alexandra ""Alex""",Menendez,alex.menendez@gmail.com,Miami,1')
reader = csv.reader(infile)
for row in reader:
    print(row)

# output:
# ['Alexandra "Alex"', 'Menendez', 'alex.menendez@gmail.com', 'Miami', '1']
```

Comment: Thanks but I would want to do it without csv library.

Comment: @Arman Why don't you want to use the `cvs` module? With this you can then easily add each row to a `list` or `dict` in the `for` loop.What is your end goal for this data?

Comment: May be I didn't express what my end goal is! I could have some this like SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE "Alex;" The need here is I need to get the double quotes too and if there are two double quotes I need to escape it with a \". I would want to do it without a CSV library. Also this is what i want ["Alexandra \"Alex\"", "Menendez", "alex.menendez@gmail.com", "Miami", "1"] it's different from what you get when you use csv.

Comment: @Arman What you have there is clearly csv data, so you should use the `csv` module to parse it. Then if your database module forces you to manually escape anything, you should find a different, more secure database module that escapes stuff automatically.

Comment: Well, let's not get to the database module even. If you have any recommendation on how to parse the string to what I need, it would be helpful.

Comment: @Arman If you really have to, just call `.replace('"', '\\"')` on the output of the csv reader.

Comment: @Arman, you could also turn this into a `dict` so that you can more easily ingest it to your DB. You would loop through the list of data the `csv` module returns and and map each string to a key. At the end of the day the output is just a list of strings so you can clean them any way you want. Cleary the first element in the list output by `cvs` is middle name and first name. I would use `split` and then `replace('"', '')` to remove the double quotes around the first name.

Answer (score 0):

Say, after converting your sentence into list and iterating over every elements, do the following regsub

Consider 'a' is an element from your list

```
a= "\"Alexadra \"\"Alex\"\"\""

print(a)

y=re.sub('\"{2}', '\\\"', a)

y will replace your double quotes with \" i.e a slash with single quote

If only single quote is required try

z=re.sub('\"{2}', '\"', a)
```

Comment: Or use the `csv` module.